# PhpExcel Reader: Couldn't read certain files

Tags: php, zip, phpexcel, php-extension

Error Shows
->Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object

When uploading files, and reading excel files, sometimes it shows that error message.

This is my code:

```
$pasFile    = $_FILES['inputFileLocation']['name'];
$target_path    = basename($pasFile);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["inputFileLocation"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)){
        require_once '../template/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $worksheet_names = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($pasFile);
        $countWorksheet = count($worksheet_names);
        $optionSheetName = "<option></option>";
        for($x = 0;$x < $countWorksheet;$x++){
            $optionSheetName = $optionSheetName."<option value='".$worksheet_names[$x]."'>".$worksheet_names[$x]."</option>";
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Perhaps they're aren't proper Excel2007 xlsx files... have you tried using identify() to see what PHPExcel thinks they are, or opening them in a text editor to look and see what they contain?

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the response Mr.Baker! Finally got it working..

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer my own question right now, the system doesn't allow it. Maybe i'll post it later, so that it can help other programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake! The file that I was uploading had different types of excel format.

This code now works by identifying the format then passing it to the create reader.
Many thanks to Mr. Baker!
I added this codes:

```
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($pasFile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
```

Resulting to this one:

```
$pasFile    = $_FILES['inputFileLocation']['name'];
$target_path    = basename($pasFile);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["inputFileLocation"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)){
        require_once '../template/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($pasFile);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $worksheet_names = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($pasFile);
        $countWorksheet = count($worksheet_names);
        $optionSheetName = "<option></option>";
        for($x = 0;$x < $countWorksheet;$x++){
            $optionSheetName = $optionSheetName."<option value='".$worksheet_names[$x]."'>".$worksheet_names[$x]."</option>";
        }
    }
```

identify() first before createReader()...